# How to use ReactiveUI::WhenAnyValue correctly with alternate windows threads?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, reactiveui

I have built a small logging GUI to help debug the main application. It needs to run on it's own thread so it is not blocked when the main UI becomes unresponsive. Part of the purpose of the logging window is to find out why the main window becomes unresponsive.

The new window is launched via this method.

```
    public static Task<T> CreateAndShowStaWindow<T>(Func<T> factory) where T:Window
    {

        var windowResult = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();

        var newWindowThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            var window = factory();
            window.Show();
            windowResult.SetResult( window );
            window.Events().Closed.Subscribe( _ => window.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown() );
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();

        });
        newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
        newWindowThread.Start();
        newWindowThread.Name = "STA WPF";

        return windowResult.Task;
    }
```

Inside the window I have a textbox

```
<TextBox x:Name="FilterText"/>
```

which I wish to monitor for changes using ReactiveUI [WhenAnyValue](https://docs.reactiveui.net/en/user-guide/when-any/)

```
this
      .WhenAnyValue( p => p.FilterText.Text )
      .Subscribe( Console.WriteLine);
```

Now I am sure the above **call** to  WhenAnyValue is run on the new STA thread. I can check this in the debugger.

[image]

and

[image]

If I let the program continue I get

> InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

This exception occurs on **"MAIN"** thread rather than the **"STA WPF"** thread and at this point in the stack

```
ReactiveUI.dll!ReactiveUI.Reflection.TryGetValueForPropertyChain<object>(out object changeValue, object current, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression> expressionChain) Line 129   
ReactiveUI.dll!ReactiveUI.ReactiveNotifyPropertyChangedMixin.observedChangeFor(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expression, ReactiveUI.IObservedChange<object, object> sourceChange) Line 134 
ReactiveUI.dll!ReactiveUI.ReactiveNotifyPropertyChangedMixin.nestedObservedChanges(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expression, ReactiveUI.IObservedChange<object, object> sourceChange, bool beforeChange) Line 142
ReactiveUI.dll!ReactiveUI.ReactiveNotifyPropertyChangedMixin.SubscribeToExpressionChain.AnonymousMethod__1(ReactiveUI.IObservedChange<object,> object> y) Line 104
```

[image]

With WPF it is not allowed to make cross thread access to WPF dependency properties. The question is *why is ReactiveUI making a cross thread access*?

Note that the error is **not** happening in the `Console.WriteLine` callback as passed to the subscription. It occurs inside the reactiveui code as it tries to read the `Text` property of the `TextBox`. Adding

```
this
      .WhenAnyValue( p => p.FilterText.Text )
      .ObserveOn(DispatcherScheduler.Current)
      .Subscribe( Console.WriteLine);
```

does not fix the problem. Neither does

```
this
     .WhenAnyValue(p => p.FilterText.Text)
     .SubscribeOn( DispatcherScheduler.Current )
     .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

As a santiy check if I **remove** the WhenAnyValue call from the code then I don't get this error.

It seems that ReactiveUI is getting confused with which synchronization context it should be operating on. But maybe I'm doing something wrong. Is there a solution / workaround to this problem?

## EDIT

To reproduce the error you will need to insert a call to

```
   Locator.CurrentMutable.InitializeReactiveUI();
```

some point early in the application startup. A project that replicates the bug is here.

https://github.com/bradphelan/RxUIBug1375

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: What does your factory() method do?

Comment: @mm8 Creates a window. `CreateAndShowStaWindow(()=>new LoggerWindow())` for example. You can return any subclass of window.

Answer (score 1):

> But maybe I'm doing something wrong

Probably because it works for me if I create the window like this:

```
Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(
        new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));

    RxWindow tempWindow = new RxWindow();
    tempWindow.Closed += (ss, ee) => Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);
    tempWindow.Show();

    Dispatcher.Run();
}));
newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
newWindowThread.Start();
newWindowThread.Name = "STA WPF";
```

**RxWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class RxWindow : Window
{
    public RxWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.WhenAnyValue(p => p.FilterText.Text)
            .Subscribe(_ => MessageBox.Show(""));
    }
}
```

Comment: I've extract my code into a new project and I can't reproduce the error. I've even copied a much larger chunk of my project into a new project and there is still no error. However thanks for attempting the replication. I'm currently puzzling over what the real problem might be.

Comment: I have found a way to reproduce. The trick is to insert a call to `  Locator.CurrentMutable.InitializeReactiveUI();` somewhere in the code before running. Then it fails. Reproduction project is https://github.com/bradphelan/RxUIBug1375 and issue being tracked at https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI

Answer (score 0):

**[Update]**

I didn't understand the question correctly. You could probably use `SubscribeOn`, but having it default to the calling context instead of the main thread would be nicer indeed.

**[Old]**

Your breakpoint is set on the line defining the WhenAny call. When the WhenAny subscription is defined, you can be sure it's on your STA thread. But the subscription can (and often will) observe on a new thread because that's how Rx works; asynchronous.

You can confirm this by putting a breakpoint on the method you pass to `Subscribe()`, you'll see it's being called from a different thread.

You can use the `.ObserveOn()` method to define on which thread the subscription will be observed.

RxUI has an IScheduler set up to reference your main thread: `RxApp.MainThreadScheduler`, you can pass this directly to `.ObserveOn()`.

```
this
  .WhenAnyValue( p => p.FilterText.Text )
  .ObserveOn( RxApp.MainThreadScheduler )
  .Subscribe( Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: Yes I know where I set my breakpoint. The point being is that ReactiveUI should take note of the synchronization context and not switch threads for any part of the chain. The window is spawned on thread "STA WPF". The initialization code is run on "STA WPF". There is no good reason why anything should be dispatched on thread "MAIN".

Comment: And the code you have wrote will still fail. (for two reasons ) (1) The error occurs when the framework tries to read the dependency property _FilterText.Text_ on the wrong thread. ObserveOn does not change this. It will only deliver the resulting value downstream on dispatcher you have passed. (2) If you read the question you will see that I am not using the RxApp.MainThreadScheduler, I have started a new dispatcher on a new thread.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with WPF, so I was guessing a STA thread would be the main thread, but it seems I was wrong. :)

Comment: Ok. No problem. Would be good to delete the question so nobody gets confused.

Comment: FYI. It is not a common thing to spawn a new thread to run new windows. I just have a special case where it is useful to me and have run into a problem. :)

Comment: A way around this would probably be to use `SubscribeOn`, but I agree it would be nice if it would honor the calling context by default.

Comment: That also doesn't work. ( I did try it ). Something is forcibly dispatching to the main thread. I've tried to find the offending code in the RXUI codebase but I can't see anything obvious wrong.

Comment: I've updated the question to indicate that your new suggestion does not work. SubscribeOn is normally only useful if the _current_ synchronization context is not where you want the subscription code to run. In this case the _current_ synchronization context is exactly where I want it to run but something is bumping some of the code to the main thread.